# Assuming $\sum n a_n$ converges, does it follow that $\sum a_n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let us assume that the series 
$$\sum n a_n$$
converges.

Does it follow that the series
$$\sum a_n$$
converge ?

In case the series were positive, it's trivial using the comparison test. What can we say in the general case ?

Comment: Have a look at [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Answer (score 4):

Let us rephrase the question as: if we know that $\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n$ is convergent, do we also know that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{b_n}{n}$ is convergent? The answer is *yes* and the technique for proving it is [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts). Let us set $B_n=b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n$. We have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{b_n}{n} = \frac{B_N}{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{B_n}{n(n+1)} $$
where $B_N\to L$ implies that $\frac{B_N}{N}\to 0$ as $N\to +\infty$. It also implies that the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{B_n}{n(n+1)}$ is absolutely convergent by asymptotic comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$.

---

Slight generalization with the same proof: if $\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n$ is convergent and $\varepsilon>0$, then $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{b_n}{n^{\varepsilon}}$ is convergent, too.

---

This also has an interesting sort of converse, known as [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma): if $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{b_n}{n}$ is convergent, then $\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n =0$.